# Change Initial View Controller for First Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I know this question has been asked but the methods are not working for me. I have a view controller that contains a tutorial, which I only want to display as the initial view the first time the app is opened. After that, the main menu will always be the initial view. The storyboard ID for my Tutorial screen is "Tutorial". I have the following code to detect first launch, but I can't figure out how to make the tutorial appear:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey: @"FirstLaunch"])
{}
else{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change initial controller in two ways:

1. Check 'Is Initial VC' checkbox at Interface Builder or
2. Configure it at -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

**Changing initial view controller using Application Delegate**

In -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in your application delegate (AppDelegate.m) add if/else to check the necessity of tutorial:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"FirstLaunch"])
    {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       /*** load vc ***/
    }
    return YES;
}
```

To set the initial controller you have to initialize window property, create vc and set it as root:

```
// 1. Initialize window
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
// 2. Get storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
// 3. Create vc
TutorialViewController *tutorialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([TutorialViewController class])];
// 4. Set as root
self.window.rootViewController = tutorialViewController;
// 5. Call to show views
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get the error message "Property 'storyboard' not found on object of type 'App Delegate'" Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for comment! Edited my answer. You can find your storyboard name at your main target info screen. Usually it's called 'Main' or 'Main_iphone'

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm getting an error message saying "use of undeclared identifier 'navigator VC'" How could I fix this issue? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Edited my answer. I usually embed view controllers in navigation controllers. Forgot to delete navigation controller entity. Now code is right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But now I am getting the error message "Unknown receiver 'TutorialViewController': Did you mean 'UISplitViewController'?" When I did change it to UISplitViewController the code runs, but the tutorial screen shows up every time the app opens :(

Comment: And it's right because you always set tutorial view controller as root. You can access user defaults to check if it's necessary to run tutorial and set Tutorial VC (if needed) or your Main VC (if not) as root controller;